# Returning attribute value using Xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

I need to return cno and the zip

> x in customers/customer
>
> z in customers/customer/city
>
> return {data($x/@cno)}
>
> {$z/zipcode}
>
> It returns every cno, I need zip code that matches cno

```
<customers>
<customer cno="2222">
        <city>
        <zip>67226</zip>
        <phone>316-636-5555</phone>
       </city>
    </customer>

    <customer cno="1000">
        <city>
        <zip>67226-1555</zip>
        <phone>000-000-0000</phone>
      </city>
    </customer>    

</customers>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns the result you describe:

```
xquery version "3.1";

for $customer in /customers/customer
return
    $customer/@cno || ": " || $customer/city/zip
```

The result:

```
2222: 67226
1000: 67226-1555
```

Complete sample code can be found at http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhv.

Comment: <company>
          <employee name="Brock">
          <department> 
          <dname> Marketing</dname>
          <salary> 5555</salary>
          </department> 
          </employee>
          </company>

Still confused, when I use the same method to get the name and the salary. I just get the salary. I am using Base X, Does it matter?

Comment: Are you getting different results with my code in BaseX?

Comment: Please specify which ”same method” you mean and provide a code sample of what is not working and what result you expect.